# SQL -> CSV (utf8-BOM header not working correctly)

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am using this code below to export my MySQL data into .CSV file. All working fine, but when I trying to export these letters `ě, š, č, ř, ž, ý, á, í, é` (Czech alphabet), the letters `ě, ř, č` are exported as `?`. The other letters are exported fine.

Can you help me solve this problem please?

```
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server    = "xxx";                          //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username  = "xxx";                          //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password  = "xxx";                          //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName    = "xxx";                          //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName   = "wp_comments";                           //MySQL Table Name
$DB_Query     = "comment_author, comment_content";       //MySQL Query (what to select from db, you can use * for all)
$filename     = "excelfilename";                         //File Name
$filename_columns = array("Autor", "Content");           //File Name of columns
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/ 

//headers
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.csv;');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  

//create MySQL connection  
mysql_connect($DB_Server,$DB_Username,$DB_Password);
mysql_select_db($DB_DBName);
$sql = "SELECT $DB_Query FROM $DB_TBLName";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');   
$fp = fwrite($fh, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) )); // Write UTF-8 BOM
if($fp)
{
    fwrite($fh, "sep=\t" . PHP_EOL);   // Hint for MS Excel
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        fputcsv($fh, $row, "\t");
    }
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Try to use class from this question to convert all string to utf-8.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140358/php-glob-directory-utf8/23140525#23140525

Comment: @eggyal yes I am sure, here is some screenshots: [Database content](http://i.imgur.com/zlx2vLc.png) and [Exported DB content](http://i.imgur.com/zWCit3A.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're not explicitly setting the [encoding of the database connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html), the default encoding with which `libmysql` was compiled (usually latin1) will be used.  In transcoding the resultset to that character set, MySQL replaces any characters which it cannot represent with `?`.

To avoid this, you should be calling [`mysql_set_charset('utf8')`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) after opening the database connection—see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279).

That said, you really shouldn't be using ext/mysql at all: it is now deprecated and the manual has contained warnings against its use in new code for almost three years.  Consider [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Finally, if the MySQL server is on the same machine as PHP and you have the `FILE` privilege, why not avoid handing the data to PHP altogether and simply use MySQL's [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) command to generate the output file?

```
//create MySQL connection  
$DB_DSN = "mysql:host=$DB_Server;dbname=$DB_DBName;charset=utf8";
new PDO($DB_DSN, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)->exec("
  SELECT $DB_Query
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/$filename.tsv'
  CHARACTER SET utf8
  FROM $DB_TBLName
");

echo "\xef\xbb\xbf"       // Write UTF-8 BOM
   , "sep=\t", PHP_EOL;   // Hint for MS Excel

readfile("/tmp/$filename.tsv");
```

Beware that you may need to ensure that the temporary file is not in use by a concurrent process.

PS: The format is only called CSV ("comma separated values") when the field delimiter is the comma character; when using a tab character as the field delimiter, the format is more correctly called TSV ("tab separated values") and should have the `.tsv` or `.tab` extension.

Comment: I cannot use this solution `INTO OUTFILE` in my webhosting

Comment: @pes502: The above answer offers more than just that one solution.  The second paragraph, in particular, explains how you can fix your current attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not recommended by the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) you could try to use the "old way" to set up the connection character set via SQLs: `SET NAMES utf8;` and then `SET CHARACTER SET utf8;` just after you've selected the database.

Note: the order of these two statements matter!

**Edit #1**

I've just noticed that in **eggyal**'s answer the only problem you have is the lack of `INTO OUTFILE` privilege. You should try to use the method described in eggyal's second paragraph, that is using `the mysql_set_charset('utf8')` right after selecting your database instead.