# PHP glob function with directories using special characters

Tags: php, directory, glob

Having directory named "Łęć"
and using glob like this:

```
$dirs = glob( FILES . '/general/*' );
```

Gives me the result of:

```
...
(string) "../pliki/general/Logo"
(string) "../pliki/general/���"
(string) "../pliki/general/Maski"
...
```

And this `���` is the directory named `Łęć`

I totally can't figure it out how to make it work, so I can have folders with special characters and the glob() to work with it properly

```
                    $dirs = glob( FILES . '/general/q/*' );
                    foreach($dirs as &$dir)
                    {
                        $dir = bin2hex($dir);
                    }
                    dd($dirs);
```

This code above globs where `Łęć` folder is and bin2hex it's name returns: `2e2e2f706c696b692f67656e6572616c2f712fa3eae6` and the folder name alone without the path is `a3eae6`

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let us know pls :- [PHP glob directory UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140358/php-glob-directory-utf-8)

Comment: You saved your script with UTF-8 without a BOM?
Under which system do you get this result?

Comment: This does not help, instead of `ŁĘĆ` now I had `£ÊÆ` @KenLee

Comment: @jspit it worked on Windows, but doesnt work on production server, Linux. The file is saved as UTF-8 without a BOM and with LF line endings

Comment: Did you set the correct header:
header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset = UTF-8');

Comment: @jspit `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$dirs = glob( FILES . '/general/*' );
dd($dirs);` and still `���`

Comment: I created a Łęć directory on a Linux system with mkdir() and glob() returns it correct . Your file system must use an encoding other than UTF-8. You first need to find the encoding of your directory. Outputting the directory name in hexadecimal format with bin2hex() can provide an indication of this.

Comment: @jspit by doing like glob these dirs and then foreach them and bin2hex the name?

Comment: Yes. In the end, for /Łęć, this comes to me after bin2hex: 2fc581c499c487

Comment: @jspit by doing bin2hex on this dirname from glob I have `2e2e2f706c696b692f67656e6572616c2f712fa3eae6`. I did edit the topic also with code and this result

Comment: @jspit and the foldername alone without the path is `a3eae6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a3eae6 is the hexadecimal representation of the string of unknown encoding returned for "Łęć". The string returned by glob() can write in PHP-Notation as "\xa3\xea\xe6". The conversion of this character string with an encoding unknown to us into UTF-8 must then result "Łęć".

Through trial and error, I found that the "ISO-8859-2" encoding satisfies this condition:

```
$strCode = "\xa3\xea\xe6";
$name = mb_convert_encoding($strCode,"UTF-8","ISO-8859-2");
var_dump($name === "Łęć"); //bool(true)
```

The strings that glob returns must all be converted with mb_convert_encoding:

```
$fullNameUTF8 = mb_convert_encoding($strFromGlob,"UTF-8","ISO-8859-2");
```

This procedure is not certain. It's better to know the exact encoding used by the file system you are accessing.

Comment: Amazing, you really did it and figured it out. gz and thanks. I just wonder how it can be that as u say; the filesystem uses the ISO-8859-2. I am using one of the most popular Polish hostings called nazwa.pl. It's kinda strange theyre using the ISO-8859-2. I thought by now UTF-8 is standard.

Comment: Do you use Windows ? Your hosting should be able to tell you exactly what encoding is used. There are a number of encodings that are very similar to ISO-8859-2.